# Do movie bundles get prorated for the movies already owned?

Tags: itunes, itunes-store, movie

I'd like to know whether the iTunes movie bundles get prorated similarly like App bundles:

e.g. I already own the [The Shawshank Redemption](https://itunes.apple.com/us/movie/the-shawshank-redemption/id282875479), would I get priced the full price of [The Shawshank Redemption / The Green Mile 2-Film](https://itunes.apple.com/us/movie-collection/the-shawshank-redemption-the-green-mile-2-film/id1608445159) (this is just a simple example, I'm asking because I have 3/9 movies from [King of Horror: Expanded Edition 9 Film Collection](https://itunes.apple.com/us/movie-collection/king-of-horror-expanded-edition-9-film-collection/id1609670360) and I'd like to complete that collection)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Movie bundles are not prorated for movies you have already bought.

I took the plunge and purchased the bundle containing a previously bought movie.

You get the dialog below, after payment confirmation, asking you if you'd like to proceed with full amount. The dialog says:

> You have already purchased some of the items on this Movie Bundle. Are you sure you want to purchase the entire Movie Bundle?

[image: purchase dialog]